# Application not responding after implementing Scope Storage

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11, android-storage, android-internal-storage

I implemented Scope Storage in a sample project. Where I **Save**, **Load**, and **Modify** Images in **Local Storage** and in **Scope Storage** as well.
Below is my Main Activity Class where I am Saving, Loading, and Modifying images in Local and Scope Storage. The below Code was working in API level 28 or Android 10. but when I run this app in Android 11 it gets hang and gives **Application Not Responding**. I am unable to find any error in Logcat. Below is my code Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.scopestorage">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ScopeStorage">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now Below is my Main Activity Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var internalStoragePhotoAdapter: InternalStoragePhotoAdapter
    private lateinit var externalStoragePhotoAdapter: SharedPhotoAdapter

    private var readPermissionGranted = false
    private var writePermissionGranted = false
    private lateinit var permissionsLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>
    private lateinit var intentSenderLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest>

    private lateinit var contentObserver: ContentObserver

    private var deletedImageUri: Uri? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        internalStoragePhotoAdapter = InternalStoragePhotoAdapter {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                val isDeletionSuccessful = deletePhotoFromInternalStorage(it.name)
                if(isDeletionSuccessful) {
                    loadPhotosFromInternalStorageIntoRecyclerView()
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Photo successfully deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Failed to delete photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
        externalStoragePhotoAdapter = SharedPhotoAdapter {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                deletePhotoFromExternalStorage(it.contentUri)
                deletedImageUri = it.contentUri
            }
        }
        setupExternalStorageRecyclerView()
        initContentObserver()

        permissionsLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
            readPermissionGranted = permissions[Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] ?: readPermissionGranted
            writePermissionGranted = permissions[Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] ?: writePermissionGranted

            if(readPermissionGranted) {
                loadPhotosFromExternalStorageIntoRecyclerView()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can't read files without permission.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
        updateOrRequestPermissions()

        intentSenderLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) {
            if(it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    lifecycleScope.launch {
                        deletePhotoFromExternalStorage(deletedImageUri ?: return@launch)
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Photo deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Photo couldn't be deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        val takePhoto = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview()) {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                val isPrivate = binding.switchPrivate.isChecked
                val isSavedSuccessfully = when {
                    isPrivate -> savePhotoToInternalStorage(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), it)
                    writePermissionGranted -> savePhotoToExternalStorage(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), it)
                    else -> false
                }
                if(isPrivate) {
                    loadPhotosFromInternalStorageIntoRecyclerView()
                }
                if(isSavedSuccessfully) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Photo saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Failed to save photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }

        binding.btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener {
            takePhoto.launch()
        }

        setupInternalStorageRecyclerView()
        loadPhotosFromInternalStorageIntoRecyclerView()
        loadPhotosFromExternalStorageIntoRecyclerView()
    }

    private fun initContentObserver() {
        contentObserver = object : ContentObserver(null) {
            override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean) {
                if(readPermissionGranted) {
                    loadPhotosFromExternalStorageIntoRecyclerView()
                }
            }
        }
        contentResolver.registerContentObserver(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            true,
            contentObserver
        )
    }

    private suspend fun deletePhotoFromExternalStorage(photoUri: Uri) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                contentResolver.delete(photoUri, null, null)
            } catch (e: SecurityException) {
                val intentSender = when {
                    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R -> {
                        MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(contentResolver, listOf(photoUri)).intentSender
                    }
                    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q -> {
                        val recoverableSecurityException = e as? RecoverableSecurityException
                        recoverableSecurityException?.userAction?.actionIntent?.intentSender
                    }
                    else -> null
                }
                intentSender?.let { sender ->
                    intentSenderLauncher.launch(
                        IntentSenderRequest.Builder(sender).build()
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun loadPhotosFromExternalStorage(): List<SharedStoragePhoto> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val collection = sdk29AndUp {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
            } ?: MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

            val projection = arrayOf(
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT,
            )
            val photos = mutableListOf<SharedStoragePhoto>()
            contentResolver.query(
                collection,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME} ASC"
            )?.use { cursor ->
                val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
                val displayNameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
                val widthColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH)
                val heightColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT)

                while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                    val displayName = cursor.getString(displayNameColumn)
                    val width = cursor.getInt(widthColumn)
                    val height = cursor.getInt(heightColumn)
                    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        id
                    )
                    photos.add(SharedStoragePhoto(id, displayName, width, height, contentUri))
                }
                photos.toList()
            } ?: listOf()
        }
    }

    private fun updateOrRequestPermissions() {
        val hasReadPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        val hasWritePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        val minSdk29 = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q

        readPermissionGranted = hasReadPermission
        writePermissionGranted = hasWritePermission || minSdk29

        val permissionsToRequest = mutableListOf<String>()
        if(!writePermissionGranted) {
            permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }
        if(!readPermissionGranted) {
            permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }
        if(permissionsToRequest.isNotEmpty()) {
            permissionsLauncher.launch(permissionsToRequest.toTypedArray())
        }
    }

    private suspend fun savePhotoToExternalStorage(displayName: String, bmp: Bitmap): Boolean {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val imageCollection = sdk29AndUp {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
            } ?: MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "$displayName.jpg")
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH, bmp.width)
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT, bmp.height)
            }
            try {
                contentResolver.insert(imageCollection, contentValues)?.also { uri ->
                    contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri).use { outputStream ->
                        if(!bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, outputStream)) {
                            throw IOException("Couldn't save bitmap")
                        }
                    }
                } ?: throw IOException("Couldn't create MediaStore entry")
                true
            } catch(e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setupInternalStorageRecyclerView() = binding.rvPrivatePhotos.apply {
        adapter = internalStoragePhotoAdapter
        layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, RecyclerView.VERTICAL)
    }

    private fun setupExternalStorageRecyclerView() = binding.rvPublicPhotos.apply {
        adapter = externalStoragePhotoAdapter
        layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, RecyclerView.VERTICAL)
    }

    private fun loadPhotosFromInternalStorageIntoRecyclerView() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val photos = loadPhotosFromInternalStorage()
            internalStoragePhotoAdapter.submitList(photos)
        }
    }

    private fun loadPhotosFromExternalStorageIntoRecyclerView() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val photos = loadPhotosFromExternalStorage()
            externalStoragePhotoAdapter.submitList(photos)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun deletePhotoFromInternalStorage(filename: String): Boolean {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                deleteFile(filename)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                false
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun loadPhotosFromInternalStorage(): List<InternalStoragePhoto> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val files = filesDir.listFiles()
            files?.filter { it.canRead() && it.isFile && it.name.endsWith(".jpg") }?.map {
                val bytes = it.readBytes()
                val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
                InternalStoragePhoto(it.name, bmp)
            } ?: listOf()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun savePhotoToInternalStorage(filename: String, bmp: Bitmap): Boolean {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                openFileOutput("$filename.jpg", MODE_PRIVATE).use { stream ->
                    if(!bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, stream)) {
                        throw IOException("Couldn't save bitmap.")
                    }
                }
                true
            } catch(e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                false
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        contentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(contentObserver)
    }
}
```

Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you also attach the anr logs? You can pull them using adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt

Comment: Do I have to write this on the terminal? This command?

Comment: Yup more about it here—> https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr

Comment: adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/data/anr/traces.txt': No such file or directory
Getting this again and again.